# How to calculate work, when force vector is diagonal, and object is moved diagonally at a different angle?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, work, distance

Suppose I have this scenario:

> (a) The force vector is  $[2,    4]$. (This means the $x$ component of the vector is $2$, and $y = 4$ ).
>
> (b) The object is moved diagonally $[5,    6]$. (This means the object is moved, $5$ units in the $x$-direction, and $6$ units in the $y$-direction).
>
> (c) Please note that the *angle of the force vector* is different from the *angle* by which the object is moved diagonally.

(**Note**: Assume that all units given above are correct, and there is no need for any unit conversion.)

Can I calculate the total work by adding the work in the $x$-direction to the work in the $y$-direction as follow?

> $$\text{Work }=\text{ Force}\cdot\text{Distance}$$

1. Work in the $x$-direction:

$$W_1=2\cdot5=10$$

2. Work in the $y$-direction:

$$W_2=4\cdot6=24$$

3. Total Work:

$$W=W_1+W_2=10+24=34$$

(**Note**: Again, assume that all units given are correct, and there is no need for any unit conversion.)

---

Would anyone please let me know if that calculation is correct?

(Note: This is not a homework problem from school. It is just for my own understanding. Thanks.)

Comment: Yes, your answer is correct. You may want to look into the dot product and the true definition of [work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_(physics)), $W = \int \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{r}$.

Comment: @DevrimA, Thanks for the answer. I will check out the wiki link about the definition of "WORK" that you provided.